# Is this sorting algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying question 2.3-7 in CLRS, which states:

Describe a theta(n log(n))-time algorithm that, given a set S of n integers and another integer x, determines whether or not there exist two elements in S whose sum is exactly x.

My algorithm is the following:

```
1. Sort(S)
2. S' = x - Sort(S)  (subtracts x from each element in sorted S) 
3. for each y in S' check if y in Sort(S) if not return NIL
4. For a y satisfying condition 3 let S'' = Sort(S)+y
5. Return the index of value v in S'' which equals x and return (v-y,y) from S
```

This is seems to run in theta(n lg(n)) time because we can do

1. In theta(n(lg(n)) time with Merge Sort
2. In O(n) time
3. In theta(nlg(n)) time Binary Search for each of the n elements in S'
4. In O(n) time
5. In O(n) time

The sum is theta(n log(n)). Is this correct?

Comment: for me it seems correct

Comment: It is needlessly complicated. Once you have S sorted, you can find two elements summing to x (or stating that they do not exist) in linear time. This does not change the overall time complexity, but gives a much simpler algorithm.

Comment: In your algorithm I suppose 4 and 5 are included in loop 3, right? In worst case S' has the same size as S if x is big enough and greater than Max(S).
I thought first of solving this my doing a sort and a decrease_max increase_min of numbers below x ... but I have no idea of the complexity.

Comment: I think @Henry is correct . In your approach you are storing a lot of data again which increases the space complexity, You could just sort the array and use the 2 pointer approach to solve the problem in nlog(n) which constant space complexity

Comment: This can be done in linear time with O(n) space complexity using HashMaps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in linear time with O(n) space complexity using HashMaps.

```
    private Boolean testElementSum(List<Integer> list, int sumNumber) {
        HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int x : list) {
            if (map.containsKey(x))
                return (map.get(x));

            map.put(sumNumber - x, true);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Test
    private void testSum() {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 9, 20, 33);
        Assert.assertTrue(testFummy(list, 29));
        Assert.assertTrue(testFummy(list, 3));
        Assert.assertTrue(testFummy(list, 53));
        Assert.assertTrue(testFummy(list, 12));
        Assert.assertFalse(testFummy(list, 100));
        Assert.assertFalse(testFummy(list, 0));
    }
```